# How to getText() of particular links - Selenium Webdriver - TestNG?

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver, testng, xpath-2.0

#### Samsung Galaxy S4

I want to  verify if all the links has the text "Samsung Galaxy "
this is the link I am trying to work on. http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_sacat=0&_from=R40&_nkw=samsung+galaxy&rt=nc
I searched "samsung galaxy" and want to very if the search page displayed correct links i.e. Samsung galaxy products

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Sample 
{

WebDriver driver;
@BeforeClass
public void BeforeClass() throws InterruptedException, IOException
{
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_sacat=0&_from=R40&_nkw=samsung+galaxy&rt=nc");
    Thread.sleep(4000);

}
@Test
public void fetchCustKeys() throws Exception
{
    WebElement results = driver.findElement(By.id("ResultSetItems"));
    List<WebElement> allLinks = results.findElements(By.xpath("//h3/a"));
    for(WebElement w: allLinks)
    {
        w.getText();
        if (w.getText().toLowerCase().contains("samsung galaxy"))
        {
            System.out.println(w.getText()+"is Valid Link");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println(w.getText()+"is not Valid");
        }
    }
}
```